# Formatting modifiers for a string inside stringWithFormat?

Tags: objective-c

i need a String formated like this:

```
-(void)updateResult:(NSString*)name withAmount:(int)amount
{
    NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%15@ with %8i €",name,amount];
    ...
}
```

The int format works, but the string format doesn't. I need a String, that uses 15 characters. If the string is shorter, e.g. 10 character, the remaining 5 ones should be replaced with an empty space.

can you help please

regards camelord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `%s` which does accept the length modifier.

```
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%15s with %8i €",
                                              [name UTF8String], amount];
```